# All my activity has been deleted

Tags: support

I've been a user of Server Fault for almost a year, and have asked a few questions in that time (I've been much more active in Stack Overflow).

I had a look at my profile this morning and see that all my Quesions are gone!

I asked a question yesterday, which was the reason for checking my profile this morning.

What happened to my questions?

Comment: What was the title of the question you asked yesterday? Or can you find it [here](http://serverfault.com/questions?sort=newest)?

Answer (score 7):

I see that your account as it is now, has done question on it which you deleted yourself on the 11th of May 2011.

Apart from that, I see no activity from your account at all. Which means one of the following:

- You have multiple accounts. I have done a quick search and can only find the account you posted this question from, but if you used a different Open ID, Email address or display name I might have trouble finding your other account.
- You're on the wrong site. This is unlikely because you specifically mention Server Fault in your question, but it does happen! I see that [you asked a question on Stack Overflow on the 11th of March](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331262/task-continuation-on-ui-thread). Could that be it?
- Gremlins ate your question (highly unlikely).

I don't suppose you remember what your missing question was about? If we can track down the question, then we can find what happened to it.

Content is never permanantly deleted from the site, it always hangs around and can be undeleted, if we can just find it.

Comment: I couldn't find anything else network-wide matching "sansom".  Up to Greg to give us a little more info :)

Comment: @Mark, thanks for looking into this.  I'm feeling very silly now as it was option 2.

Comment: @GregSansom - no worries, happens to the best of us

Comment: Pity. I would have loved to actually see option 3.